# No sobrescribir un arreglo en c++

Tags: c++, array

por falta de conocimiento no se como hacer para no sobrescribir mi arreglo, el programa trata de un estacionamiento en el cual se van asignando cocheras que van de 1 a 20. Y ademas cuenta con mas opciones, como poder retirar el vehículo y que se libere la cochera asignada. **Pero en esta porción de código lo que sucede es que una vez que salgo de la opción y luego quiero ingresar otro vehículo, reescribe sobre los que ya estan ingresados, eliminando los anteriores, Como lo soluciono?**

```
    estacionamiento ingresoVehiculo (int totalCocheras[num]){
    estacionamiento vehiculo;
    int i = 0;
        if(i < num){
        cout<<"Ingrese la patente del vehiculo (LL-NNN-LL) : ";
        cin.getline(vehiculo.patente,10,'\n');
        cin.ignore();
        validaPatente (vehiculo);
        cout<<"Ingrese hora:minutos de entrada, respetando el formato de ejemplo: ";
        cin >> vehiculo.horaMinutos;
        cin.ignore();
        validarHora(vehiculo);
        cout<<"Numero de chochera asignado: ";
        vehiculo.numCochera=totalCocheras[i];
        cout<<vehiculo.numCochera<<endl;
        vehiculo.ocupado=true;
        i++;
        }
        return vehiculo;
      

}
    void ingresoVehiculos (vector<estacionamiento> cocherasOcupadas){
        bool continuar=true;
        for(int i=0;i<num && continuar;i++) 
        {
          cocherasOcupadas[i]=ingresarVehiculo();
          continuar=Continuar();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo puedes resolver de varias maneras:

**Eliminas del array las cocheras ocupadas (std::vector)**

Para este caso necesitas crear una estructura un poco más compleja que un simple array. Lo suyo sería emplear un contendor de la stl como `std::vector`:

Inicializas el vector:

```
std::vector<int> cocheras;
for(int i=1; i<=MAX_COCHERAS; i++)
    cocheras.push_back(i);
```

Ahora en las reservas sacas el último elmento de la lista (o el primero, como prefieras):

```
estacionamiento ingresoVehiculo(std::vector<int> & cocheras)
{
    // ...
    vehiculo.num_cochera = cocheras.back(); // recuperamos el último elemento
    cocheras.pop_back();                    // y lo sacamos de la lista
}
```

Y cuando el vehículo abandona la cochera, simplemente vuelves a meter el elemento en el contenedor:

```
void sacar_vehiculo(estacionamiento const& vehiculo, std::vector<int> & cocheras)
{
    // ...
    cocheras.push_back(vehiculo.num_cochera);
}
```

**Eliminas del array las cocheras ocupadas (a mano)**

Si no puedes usar `std::vector` entonces tendrás que gestionar el array a mano.

En este caso lo suyo, por simpleza, sería encapsular el array en una clase para usarlo más cómodamente:

```
class Cocheras
{
private:
    int * cocheras;
    int max_elementos;
    int indice;

public:
    Cocheras(int max_elementos)
        : cocheras{ new int[max_elementos] }
        , max_elementos{ max_elementos }
        , indice{ max_elementos }
    {
        for(int i=0; i<max_elementos;i++)
            cocheras[i] = i+1; 
    }

    void push_back(int valor)
    {
        if (indice== max_elementos)
            throw std::runtime_error("No se pueden insertar mas elementos");

        cocheras[indice] = valor;
        indice++; 
    }

    int pop_back()
    {
        if (indice == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("La lista esta vacia");

        indice--;
        return cocheras[indice];
    }
};
```

Con esta clase ya podrías aplicar la misma solución que en el caso anterior.

**Cada cochera almacena su estado**

Otra opción sería que una cochera almacenase su estado:

```
class Cochera
{
private:
    int numero;
    bool ocupada;

public:

    Cochera(int numero)
        : numero{numero}
        , ocupada{false}
    { }

    int getNumero() const
    { return numero; }

    bool getOcupada() const
    { return ocupada; }

    void setOcupada(bool estado)
    { ocupada = estado; }
};
```

Ahora creas un array de objetos de tipo Cochera en vez del array de enteros:

```
Cochera cocheras[] = { {1}, {2}, {3}, ... };
```

Entonces al ingresar un vehículo debes recorrer el array y quedarte con la primera cochera que no esté ocupada:

```
for(Cochera & cochera : cocheras)
{
    if (cochera.getOcupada() == false)
    {
        vehiculo.num_cochera = cochera.getNumero();
        cochera.setOcupada(true);
    }
}
```

Y cuando el vehículo abandone el estacionamiento ... pues marcas la cochera como libre:

```
cocheras[vehiculo.num_cochera-1].setOcupada(false);
```

Soluciones hay tantas como las que quieras pensar, las que te muestro son solo un pequeño muestrario.

Comment: El caso en que saca el último elemento de la lista es el más fácil. ¿No crees que sería buena idea cubrir el caso donde puedes sacar elementos de cualquier posición?

Comment: @Mateo no pretendo dar una solución canónica. El sitio se enriquece con respuestas diferentes. Te animo a poner la tuya :)

Comment: En cualquier caso, el supuesto se comporta como una pila. Da igual que cojas una LIFO o una FIFO... si se pudiese aparcar en cualquier sitio le tendrían que dar una directriz para elegir la plaza... no están pidiendo tanta complejidad